# Laravel 5 TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

EDIT: i get this error even for public/auth/login after pushing the Login button

Hi i'm simply trying to output a Session::flash() but I get this error message:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46
```

Here is the code:

```
public function update($id, Requests\EditPostRequest $request)
{

    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->update($request->all());
    return redirect(route('news.edit', $id))->with('success', 'Operation successful !');
}
```

And this is in my view:

```
  @if(Session::has('success'))
   <div class="alert alert-success">

    {{ Session::get('success') }}
   </div>
  @endif
```

I really need to fix that :/

Comment: Is the csrf token in your form that you are handling the post for?

Comment: I don't get what's your question

Comment: In the form where you are submitting the data that is used to update, do you not have the csrf input in place? I.e. something like `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />`

Comment: no i don't have anything that looks like <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
Should I add it to my form ?

Comment: Your script is seemingly failing because it expects this token to be set. A csrf token is supposed to prevent people from submitting data which is not a part of your form or submitting from outside of the web form provided. Many frameworks like Symfony2 do this automatically for you but I'm assuming Laravel expects you to place it there.

Comment: I just check, I used {!! Form::model($var, $var) !!} to initialize my form.
Doing it this way it automatically insert <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
so the problem does not come from this :/

Comment: @skrilled is exactly right: the `VerifyCsrfToken` is looking for an input parameter called `_token` and expects it to match what's stored on the server. Check the source of your HTML page & make sure it's there.

Comment: As an aside - your question is tagged Laravel 5 and I notice that the Laravel 5 documentation no longer includes the stuff on forms  (it *was* in the Laravel 4 documentation). I have no idea if that means it's no longer supported in Laravel 5 or if they just left it out of the docs. It may not be acting the way you think it is.

Comment: well it is http://puu.sh/icH7C/234486c6d8.png

Comment: @Kryten the laravel team was divided on server-side framework, and front-end pluggins, so laravel 5 doesn't contain the html or form facades, but still support _token, because its a server-side validation.
If you wanna install form and html stuff the front-end team page is here:
http://laravelcollective.com/

Comment: @CarlosHerreraPlata didn't know that about the reorganization of the team. I use the CSRF token, but don't use blade or the other HTML/Form classes.

Comment: Well I'm still getting the same error even after added the  _token input

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Auth Post Submit - TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875788/laravel-5-auth-post-submit-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `{{ Form::token() }}` before the closing tag of your form.

Comment: It doesn't work .. I've seen on google alot of people having this issue on xampp/wamp on windows.. they said the best thing to do is installing homestead, which sucks ..

Comment: I believe this only works if you have Laravel Collective installed

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be related to using the same key in both your local/dev environment and production one.

I'm not sure how you'd get collisions, though, given that the sessions should be independent of environment, but I was doing some local development earlier. Everything was working fine in dev, pushed my project to my other PC and than I hit the TokenMismatchException.

I had a poke around my .env file and sure enough, the keys were the same between my two environments. Changing the key in my prod environment and the TokenMismatchException went away straight away.

Just look at your token which get set if they are the same change the production key with **php artisan key:generate** , hope for you this will work, just let me know if it don't.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a CSRF token in your form?

```
<form method="post" action="someaction">
{{ csrf_field() }} // Generates an input field with a token
// Other input fields
</form>
```