# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53 in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, session-cookies, csrf

When I try to login show me token error. I have checked token in view form it's right  and when comment `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class`,
in the `Kernel.php` it makes me login but after Redirect to my dashboard I'm not logged in. I am using MAMP on mac.

```
<div>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div>
        {!! Form::open(['url'=>'user/login','class' => '']) !!}
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <ul>
          <li><label>Customer Code</label>{!!Form::Text('customer_code',Input::old('customer_code'),['class'=>''])!!}</li>
          <li><label>Password</label>{!!Form::Password('password','',['class'=>''])!!}</li>
          <li>{!! Form::submit('Submit',array('class' => 'btn')) !!}</li>
        </ul> 
        {!!Form::close()!!}
    </div>
    <div><a href="{!!URL::to('user/forget_password')!!}">Forget Password</a></div>
</div>
```

Meanwhile I use `Sentry Package` for login.

```
    /**
     * post_login
     */
    public function post_login()
    { 
        try
        {
            $rules  = [ 
                    'customer_code'         => 'required',
                    'password'              => 'required',
                ] ;                    
            $message = [ 
                    'customer_code.required'             => 'erorrr1',
                    'password.required'                =>'error2'    
                             ];                            
            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules,$message);
            if ($validator->fails())
            {            
                return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();        
            } // if ($validator->fails())
            else
            {
            $authUser = Sentry::authenticateAndRemember(array(
                                      'customer_code'    => Input::get('customer_code'),
                                      'password' => Input::get('password')), false);

                           if($authUser) 
                           {
                                //$login = Sentry::loginAndRemember($authUser);
                                 return Redirect::to('user/panel/'.$authUser->id)->with('comment', 'Welcome');
                           }
                           else
                           {
                             return Redirect::back()->with('comment', 'Error for login');
                           }
            }//validator                           
        }
         catch(\Exception $e)
         {
             return Redirect::back()->withInput(Input::except('password','file'))->withErrors(['ERROR!!!!!']);
         }
}
```

Comment: Show want code you have worked out? need more information?

Comment: How did you generate the token? show the code.

Comment: Ensure you set token on your form in the view; in a hidden field preferably

Comment: reza where is the "method" of your form????is this a GET request?plz show us your authentication logic and redirection.

Comment: I think it has POST method by default. It's necessary set it manually?

Comment: I changed email login attributes to customer_code for Sentry

Comment: When i copy from Project and rename that works right. And after sometimes show me Error....

Comment: try changing the browser. I am having problem in chrome but firefox works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Auth Post Submit - TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875788/laravel-5-auth-post-submit-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited:

Since you are using Form builder remove this from your form. Laravel form builder automatically adds a hidden token field to your form when you do `Form::open()`

So remove this line:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: i used this script already but does not worked. i have token in my form.

Comment: After you edited your question I notice you are adding to token fields. Please check my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Well I think all missed the CSRF Token creation while logout!

As I have solved out the problem.

Just add below code to the header.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<script type=text/javascript>
    $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
    });
 </script>
```

And if you use `{!!Form::open()!!}` it will automatically create the token. Otherwise you can use

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="_token" value="{!! $csrf_token !!}}" />
```

or

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

just immediate form open. 
Most importantly use `return Redirect::to('');` on controller function or a page reload or ajax reload that the token can be created!

Like:

```
public function logout() {
    Session::flush();
    Auth::logout();

    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

For ensure the token properly created or not check "view page source" on browser and it will shows like:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="TbgWTQZhTv0J4eFBQNU4rlM3jOlmBeYlTgf0waZB">
    <script type=text/javascript>
    $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
    });
    </script>


<form method="POST" action="/login-process" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-inline"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="TbgWTQZhTv0J4eFBQNU4rlM3jOlmBeYlTgf0waZB">
```

I think it might solve the problem as it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

With a fresh install of Laravel 5.1, without just a composer update from version 5.0 to 5.1 I see some differences and one in the Middleware folder.

EncryptCookies.php are a new Middleware, check if you have it.

So, I don't have tested again, I tranfert at the moment my files from my version 5.0 to a new installation of version 5.1 but im pretty sure that can be the solution for this problem, EncryptCookies.php was in the stack of the token mismatch error.

Comment: If anyone wants to except some routes from "authing" then i suggestion going to app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCrsfToken.php and add  

 protected $except = [
        'route_1',
        'route_1/*',
    ];

Answer (score 1):

Adding `{!! csrf_field() !!}` solved my problem as shown below:

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
{!! csrf_field() !!}

</form>
```

If using Laravel Form helper such as below:

```
{!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form')) !!}
```

CSRF Code will be added automatically in your html script. Also make sure to view the source code in browser to be certain that a field such as below was indeed added.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="dHWBudjTyha9AMr0SuV2ABq5NNK6bTIDZDXRWCBA">
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your sample code in your question.

Therefore check your code with the following options,

try with hidden input field value:

```
{!! csrf_token() !!} or {{ csrf_token() }}
```

You can also use form blade template:

```
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'GET/POST','url' => 'YOUR_URL',)) !!}
```

This will automatically add CSRF Code in your html script

One more thing to include in `<head>` section is:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: Remove CSRF hidden field, as you have used Form::open() CSRF will be automatically added. You also need to change your controller method name to "postLogin".

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this problem when trying to upload a file. Turned out the max_post_size was being exceeded, in which case apparently all POST variables are cleared and therefore no token is being received.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<?php echo Form::token(); ?>` in side the form.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

Add `{{ csrf_field() }}` anywhere in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code. It is working perfectly.

```
<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I am using Laravel 5.1.28, php 5.6.13
After seeing the TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken, I searched the web for answers but none solved my problem.

The page did send the token. The token values is also seen in the session file in the directory storage/framework/sessions (I disabled encryption to see it).

Exhausted, I re-install laravel and use simple form for testing - it worked without token mismatch error.

Moving my code to the newly installed laravel piece by piece, I finally found 
that the problem was caused by doctrine/dbal (I still do not know why).

Removed it from composer.json and the problem disappeared.
In the composer.json, token mismatch error was seen with the following line:

```
"require": {
    ....
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5"
    ...
},
```

Your case may be different, but you may want to see if you change anything in 
composer.json that may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem while using this code

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">

<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

by changing it to `{!! csrf_field() !!}` solve my problem

> i'm on L5.1

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

<script>
function getMessage(){ 
$.ajax({
   headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
   type:'POST',
   url:'/getmsg',
   // data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
   success:function(data){
      $("#msg").html(data.msg);
   }
 });
}
</script>

{{ Form::button('Replace Message',['onClick'=>'getMessage()']) }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` from `$middleware` in `Kernel.php`.

Comment: This should be a comment