# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

I am building a REST API using **Laravel 5.1** and I am getting this error:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:
```

Here is my **routes.php:**

```
Route::controller('city' , 'CityController' );
```

**CityController:**

```
class CityController extends Controller
{  
   public function postLocalities()
  {
    $city = Input::get('cityName');
    $response = $city;
    return $response;
   }
}
```

Here is the **Stacktrace** of the error when I hit the URL 
 http://localhost:8000/city/localities?cityName=bangalore with POST method.

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'),
array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in     
ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 54
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'),     
array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in     
StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'),   
array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in   
AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'),    
array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in     EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'),     
array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in     
CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'),   
array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('C:\Users\betaworks02\Documents\gharbhezoBackend\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Comment: Can you show us your html  form?

Comment: I haven't used any html form because I am building REST APIs for mobile app. I receive the requests through the application.

Comment: @Twreck has posted the solution. that should it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Auth Post Submit - TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875788/laravel-5-auth-post-submit-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are building an API its best to place the CRSF middle ware on per route basis rather than placing it as a global middleware. To make it as a route middleware go to the "**/app/Http/Kernel.php**" file.

```
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    //comment out to avoid CSRF Token mismatch error
    // 'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    'cors' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware',
    'api' => 'App\Http\Middleware\ApiMiddleware',
    'csrf' => 'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken'// add it as a middleware route
```

Now you can place it on the routes where you need it for example

Route::get('someRoute', array('uses' => 'HomeController@getSomeRoute', 'middleware' => 'csrf'));

For your case where you don't need CSRF token matching it should work fine now.

Comment: Ultimate! Working super fine now. I searched a lot for the right solution but everyone had solved related to html forms. You catered me with the right answer. Thank you very much :)

Comment: How to do it in Laravel5.2 ?

Answer (score 15):

You do not need to fully override the CFSR token from your app.  In your App/Http/Midlleware folder go to VerifyCsrfToken.php and include your API route to the exception as follows:

```
/**
 * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $except = [
    'api/*',
];
```

The * shows for all routes inside your API.

Comment: This answer turned out to be safer.

Comment: Best and the easiest way to do

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, but with all the warnings about overriding CSRF validation, didn't want to change those settings.

I eventually found that my Session Driver in /config/session.php was defaulting to memcached, and since I was on a development server I needed to override the SESSION_DRIVER env variable with 'file' to use the session in /storage/framework/sessions.

```
/.env

SESSION_DRIVER = file
```