# laravel csrf TokenMisMatchException, ajaxSetup is set

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, csrf

My laravel version was 5.5, and didn't have any errors in my application.
When I upgraded my laravel version to 5.6, the laravel `TokenMisMatchException` is occurring. I have set `csrf` in `meta`, `ajaxSetup` and `html form`.
I tried find solution on stackoverflow but I find just `ajaxSetup`.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

but I set this now

[image]

Comment: try a few solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875788/laravel-5-auth-post-submit-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line

Answer (score 0):

You are also need add meta tag with content.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

this works with this.

Comment: oops, sorry. did you have _token parameter in your ajax data? 
If you didn't have one. add "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/config.js"></script> // Do your $.ajaxSetup in this file 
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
    });
});
```